# How do I do ttest var1==10, by(var2) in Stata?

Tags: stata

I'm trying to run a `ttest` against a variable when it equals a certain value, but that syntax doesn't work.

How do I do `ttest var1==10, by(var2)` in Stata?

Comment: This is enough for experienced Stata users to reply, but SO standards would imply an expansion on "doesn't work".

Comment: @NickCox closed vote removed, thanks for clarification

Comment: There is a purely statistical comment on this: two t-tests in two groups implies that you should perhaps be thinking of ANOVA instead.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

`bysort var2: ttest var1==10`